# How can I find which container(s) have mounted a specific volume?

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and have been playing with it for a couple of days.

I recently came across `docker volumes` and I am having trouble figuring out this...

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               97cdb9ee214fbb2a2da04c457613c637043afe8e302ac37c4be435241742e309
local               hello
```

I don't know which container `97cdb9ee...` belongs to. I understand this was generated randomly if no name is passed.

Why is it the volume is only visible `docker volumes ls` when you do `docker run ... -v <host_dir> ...` and doesn't show when you do `docker run ... -v <host_dir>:<container_dir> ...`?

Is there a good reason for having so many anonymous volumes, besides simple test?

Edit:
It can be found on the container side `docker inspect <container>`. But it could be annoying to have to do that to all containers to figure out which one. Is it possible to rename a volume name?

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, you can find this when you inspect a container:

```
$ docker run -v /tmp --name voltest busybox true
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               4faeb87e1d603d23157564cb94fa890ab21010c3c6c91c33bcae7d1ed016f560
$ docker inspect voltest
...

 "Mounts": [
     {
                "Name": "4faeb87e1d603d23157564cb94fa890ab21010c3c6c91c33bcae7d1ed016f560",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4faeb87e1d603d23157564cb94fa890ab21010c3c6c91c33bcaed1ed016f560/_data",
                "Destination": "/tmp",

                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
     }
  ], 
...
```

You can clean these up by doing a `docker rm -v ...` on your containers. Or you can name them by doing a `docker run -v myname:/path image_name` to use a named volume called "myname". The reason to not automatically delete them is that the image author identified the location as containing data you may not want to lose accidentally with the `VOLUME` definition in their Dockerfile. But often these have no value if you already deleted the container and can be purged.